# Escape character for sql query

Tags: shell

Im using the below query in the properties file and using in the shell script but due to special characters in the query it not giving me the output with special characters.

```
query="select top 10 source_system,updt_etl_instnc_run_id,negative_posting_flag, to_number(to_varchar(to_date(create_tmstmp),'yyyymm')) as part_date from c_fin_a.gl_transaction_data where to_number(to_varchar(to_date(create_tmstmp),'yyyymm'))=$NOW and \$CONDITIONS"
```

I have used escape characters for all special chars then also its not giving me same output with escape characters.

```
 query= \ " select top 10 source_system,updt_etl_instnc_run_id,negative_posting_flag, to_number \ (to_varchar \ ( to_date \ ( create_tmstmp \ ) , \ ' yyyymm \ ' \ ) \ ) as part_date from c_fin_a.gl_transaction_data where to_number \ ( to_varchar \ ( to_date \ ( create_tmstmp \ ) , \ ' yyyymm \ ' \ ) \ )= \ $NOW and \ \$CONDITIONS \ "
```

Comment: I don't understand the question, and this isn't tagged correctly if it's a sql query then you should have a sql tag no shell tag...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: never use spaces around the equal sign when you assign a value to variable. I mean `var=value` is OK, `var = value` is not ok.

Now, let's assume your shell variables have the following values:

```
NOW=201603
CONDITIONS="city='New York'"
```

Then you need to use the following:

```
query="select top 10 source_system,updt_etl_instnc_run_id,negative_posting_flag, to_number(to_varchar(to_date(create_tmstmp),'yyyymm')) as part_date from c_fin_a.gl_transaction_data where to_number(to_varchar(to_date(create_tmstmp),'yyyymm'))=${NOW} and ${CONDITIONS}"
```

to generate a valid SQL statement.

Comment: Thank Mauro for reply.. Can you please suggest escape character for the above query?

Comment: Escape what? As I said the content of the variable named "query" here above is a valid sql statement...